# Django Foreign Key choices

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want to build an application in which a patient uploads his report to his companion doctor ,
So , I have two models one for Doctors and other for patients.
What I want is to have a relationship between the two models , in which a patient chooses his doctor from the registered doctors.

this is the code:

```
class DoctorModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctorName = models.CharField(max_length = 150 , default="")
    doctorEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default="")
    speciality  = models.CharField(choices = SPECIALITY ,max_length = 20 , default="")
    doctorStatus  = models.CharField(choices = DOCTOR_STATUS ,max_length = 15 , default="")


class PatientModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patientName = models.CharField(max_length = 150 , default="", editable=True)
    patientAge = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    patientEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default="", editable=True)
    insuranceSyndicate  = models.CharField(choices = INSURANCE_SYNDICATE, max_length = 15, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 50 , default= '')
    referencedDoctor = models.ForeignKey(DoctorModel, on_delete=models.Set_Null)
```

What I want that when a patient choose the "referencedDoctor" , he choose him from "doctorName" in the DoctorModel

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you should create __ str __ method to your models.

```
class DoctorModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctorName = models.CharField(max_length = 150 , default="")
    doctorEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default="")
    speciality  = models.CharField(choices = SPECIALITY ,max_length = 20 , default="")
    doctorStatus  = models.CharField(choices = DOCTOR_STATUS ,max_length = 15 , default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.doctorName}"
```

BTW, try use null=True to your Fields. will be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dunder string function in the Doctor model like this

```
class DoctorModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctorName = models.CharField(max_length = 150 , default="")
    doctorEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default="")
    speciality  = models.CharField(choices = SPECIALITY ,max_length = 20 , default="")
    doctorStatus  = models.CharField(choices = DOCTOR_STATUS ,max_length = 15 , default="")



    def__str__(self):
        return self.doctorName
```